# Как "прослушать" вызов метода объекта?

Tags: javascript, listener

Допустим у меня есть :

```
var Obj = {
 p : 23,
 method : function(){
  console.log( this.p++);
 }
}
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы после выполнения или  при вызове этого метода( Obj.method() )вызывались определенные функции(с возможностью их открепления/приклепления)? 
т.е. как у объектов dom

Comment: Какого *этого метода*?

Comment: Ну Obj.method()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно

```js
var Obj = {
  p: 23,
  methodLog: [],
  method: function() {
    for (i = 0; i < this.methodLog.length; i++)
      this.methodLog[i].call(this);
    console.log(this.p++);
  }
};

Obj.methodLog.push(function() {
  console.log('alerter1')
});
Obj.methodLog.push(function() {
  console.log('alerter2. p = ' + this.p)
});

Obj.method();
```